# Weyl SUSY vs Conformal SUSY

Tags: supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, superconformality

Is it possible to add the generators of dilatations to Poincare superalgebra in any dimensions with any number of supercharges without adding the full superconformal generators?

I have only seen superconformal algebras so far but never a Weyl-SUSY algebra that is the bosonic sector only consists of $\{P_a, J_{ab}, D, \text{R-symmetry generator}\}$ but not the generators of special conformal symmetry $\{K_a\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Unitary scale invariant theories are
either conformal or indistinguishable from conformal theories on
$\mathbf{R}^4$. This means that, for all practical purposes, scale invariance and unitarity imply conformality.

For review see slides ["Scale and Conformal Invariance"](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/particle/Zohar/sites/particle.Zohar/files/uploads/overview_0.pdf) by Zohar Komargodski.

Comment: My question is about the algebra, not about theories. Surely, there is an algebra with scale symmetry only that is different from the conformal algebra.